# Does vaapih264enc support profile "Baseline"?

Tags: gstreamer, debian-based, vaapi

I installed intel VAAPI driver and Gstreamer in my Debian Linux 11 system.

Install the VAAPI driver

```
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-vaapi-driver/archive/refs/tags/2.4.1.tar.gz \
&& tar -xf 2.4.1.tar.gz intel-vaapi-driver-2.4.1/ && cd intel-vaapi-driver-2.4.1/
./autogen.sh && make -j4 && sudo make install
```

But the profile "Baseline" is not listed in the src template pad of vaapih264enc.

```
gst-inspect-1.0 vaapih264enc

...
Pad Templates:
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw(memory:VASurface)
                 format: { (string)NV12, (string)YV12, (string)I420 }
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
         interlace-mode: progressive
      video/x-raw(memory:DMABuf)
                 format: { (string)NV12, (string)YV12, (string)I420 }
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
         interlace-mode: progressive
      video/x-raw
                 format: { (string)NV12, (string)YV12, (string)I420 }
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
         interlace-mode: progressive
  
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-h264
          stream-format: { (string)avc, (string)byte-stream }
              alignment: au
                profile: { (string)constrained-baseline, (string)main, (string)high }
```

Why baseline is not supported? Can I add baseline profile manually?